# fstream with a string delimiter or two char

Tags: c++, fstream

I have this situation where I need to get two int values from each row inside a file with this format:

```
43=>113
344=>22
```

Is it possible to do someting like setting a delimiter equal to => and than use >> operator to assign ints?

```
ifstream iFile("input.in");
int a,b;
iFile >> a >> b;
```

Also can be done autoamtically to output with similar format?

```
oFile << a << b;
```

instead of

```
oFile << a << "=>" << b;
```

Thanks.

Comment: A small class seems your easiest bet.

Answer (score 1):

Given `a` and `b` are variables of inbuilt types, you can not define your own user-defined operators for streaming them (the Standard library already provides such functions).

You could just write out code with the behaviour you want...

```
int a, b;
char eq, gt;

// this is probably good enough, though it would accept e.g. "29 = > 37" too.
// disable whitespace skipping with <iomanip>'s std::noskipws if you care....
if (iFile >> a >> eq >> gt >> b && eq == '=' && gt == '>')
    ...
```

**OR** wrap `a` and `b` into a `class` or `struct`, and provider user-defined operators for that.  There are plenty of SO questions with answers explaining how to write such streaming functions.

**OR** write a support function...

```
#include <iomanip>

std::istream& skip_eq_gt(std::istream& is)
{
    char eq, gt;

    // save current state of skipws...
    bool skipping = is.flags() & std::ios_base::skipws;

    // putting noskipws between eq and gt means whatever the skipws state
    // has been will still be honoured while seeking the first character - 'eq'

    is >> eq >> std::noskipws >> gt;

    // restore the earlier skipws setting...
    if (skipping)
        is.flags(is.flags() | std::ios_base::skipws);

    // earlier ">>" operations may have set fail and/or eof, but check extra reasons to do so
    if (eq != '=' || gt != '>')
        is.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit)

    return is;
}
```

...then use it like this...

```
if (std::cin >> a >> skip_eq_gt >> b)
    ...use a and b...
```

This function "works" because streams are designed to accept "io manipulator" functions that reconfigure some aspect of the stream (for example, `std::noskipws`), but for a function to be called it just has to match the prototype for an (input) io manipulator: `std::istream& (std::istream&)`.

Comment: This doesn't quite work, since it will accept things like `42 = > 3`.  (Accepting the first space if probably correct; accepting the second probably not.)

Comment: Oops.  I notice you mention this in the comment.  One possibility would be `if ( iFile >> a >> eq && iFile.get( gt ) && iFile >> b && eq == '=' && gt == '>' )`.  Personally, I prefer the manipulator.

Comment: I see. Is it possible to use the operator >> without using a variable? like: `iFile >> a >> >> >> b;`?

Comment: @CPJ: yes you can avoid a variable (can't use `>> >>` though): what's possible is to specify a function that knows to read "=>" - I'll add an example to the code above.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly, without any extra code when reading or
writing, but you can write a manipulator which handles it for
you more explicitly:

```
std::istream&
mysep( std::istream& source )
{
    source >> std::ws;      //  Skip whitespace.
    if ( source.get() != '=' || source.get() != '>' ) {
        //  We didn't find the separator, so it's an error
        source.setstate( std::ios_base::failbit );
    }
    return source;
}
```

Then, if you write:

```
ifile >> a >> mysep >> b;
```

, you will get an error is the separator is absent.

On output, you  can use a similar manipulator:

```
std::ostream&
mysep( std::ostream& dest )
{
    dest << "=>";
    return dest;
}
```

This has the advantage of keeping the information as to what the
separator is isolated in these two specific functions (which
would be defined next to one another, in the same source file),
rather than spread out where ever you are reading or writing.

Also, these data presumably represent some particular type of
information in your code.  If so, you should probably define it
as a class, and then defined operators `>>` and `<<` over that
class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have always have `=>` as the deliminator, you can write a function that will parse lines of the document.

```
void Parse(ifstream& i)
{
   string l;
   while(getline(i,l))
   {
      //First part
      string first = l.substr(0, l.find("=>"));

      //Second part
      string second = l.substr(l.find("=>")+2, l.length());

      //Do whatever you want to do with them.
   }
}
```